# WPF BitmapSource Alpha Channel Offset

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have a `BitmapSource` image that I would like to efficiently offset the alpha channel by a fixed amount i.e. `Alpha=Floor(Alpha-x)`.  What is the most efficient way to do this.  I was trying using `DrawingContext.PushOpacity()` then `DrawImage()` but this multiplies the opacity and I am really looking to do a additive offset

**Update**

I am trying to achieve an effect when text changes on my display. The idea is to fade the previous text value away when a new value is set.  I have a rough implementation but I would like input on this implementation or if there is a better strategy.  An example of how the effect should look (hard with a still image)  [image]

And the code

```
    public class TransitionalText : FrameworkElement
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TransitionalText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnTextPropertyChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TransitionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Transition", typeof(Int16), typeof(TransitionalText), new UIPropertyMetadata((Int16)255,OnTransitionPropertyChanged));

        private RenderTargetBitmap textCache, renderBitmap;
        private byte[] transitionCache;

        private void DrawText()
        {
            int stride = renderBitmap.PixelWidth * ((renderBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) >> 3);

            // Copy Current Render Scene To Cache
            renderBitmap.CopyPixels(transitionCache, stride, 0);

            // Clear Cached Text Bitmap
            textCache.Clear();

            // Render New Text Value
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
            FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(new FontFamily("lucidia"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal), 32, Brushes.Black);

            drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point(0, 0));
            drawingContext.Close();
            textCache.Render(drawingVisual);

            // Create Opacity Mask
            byte[] opacityMask = new byte[renderBitmap.PixelHeight * stride];

            // Remove Overlapping Pixels
            for (int i=3; i<opacityMask.Length; i+=4)
            {
                transitionCache[i] -= (transitionCache[i] > opacityMask[i]) ? opacityMask[i] : transitionCache[i];
            }

        }

        private void FadeTransition(int fadeValue)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < transitionCache.Length; i += 4)
            {
                transitionCache[i] -= (byte)((transitionCache[i] > fadeValue) ? fadeValue : transitionCache[i]);
            }
        }

        private void Render()
        {
            renderBitmap.Clear();
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            // Draw Transition 
            drawingContext.DrawImage(BitmapSource.Create(renderBitmap.PixelWidth, renderBitmap.PixelHeight, renderBitmap.DpiX, renderBitmap.DpiY, renderBitmap.Format, renderBitmap.Palette, transitionCache, renderBitmap.PixelWidth * ((renderBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) >> 3)), new Rect(RenderSize));
            drawingContext.DrawImage(textCache, new Rect(RenderSize));
            drawingContext.Close();

            renderBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        }


        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);


            renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)RenderSize.Width, (int)RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            textCache = (RenderTargetBitmap)renderBitmap.Clone();

            int stride = renderBitmap.PixelWidth * ((renderBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) >> 3);
        transitionCache = new byte[renderBitmap.PixelHeight * stride];

            DrawText();
            Render();

            drawingContext.DrawImage(renderBitmap, new Rect(RenderSize));

        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TransitionalText)d).OnTextPropertyChanged((string)e.NewValue);
        }
        private void OnTextPropertyChanged(string newText)
        {
            if (renderBitmap!=null)
            {
                DrawText();
                Int16Animation intAnimation = new Int16Animation(255, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
                BeginAnimation(TransitionProperty, intAnimation);
            }

        }

        private static void OnTransitionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TransitionalText)d).OnTransitionPropertyChanged((Int16)e.OldValue, (Int16)e.NewValue);
        }

        private void OnTransitionPropertyChanged(int oldValue, int newValue)
        {
            if (newValue < oldValue)
            {
                FadeTransition(oldValue - newValue);
                Render();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I can do better with parameterizing for fonts etc. but I want to know that I am not wasting my time first.  This works reasonable well as long as the change rate of the change is not too fast (looks good at 100ms not so good at 10ms however that test was just with `DispatcherTimer` so I think that the rendering was conflicting for execution time with the timer event)

I would be interested if there are better ways to achieve this result like CustomShader etc.

Thanks

Comment: @MikeT WriteableBitmap is a BitmapSource.

Comment: You'll have to modify the raw pixel data. WritableBitmap is one way to do this. Make sure not to use a pixel format with pre-multiplied RGB values, like Pbgra32.

Comment: @MikeT "a more specific implementation is required". Not if you copy the pixel buffer from one BitmapSource, modify it, and create a new BitmapSource by one of the `BitmapSource.Create()` overloads. However, WriteableBitmap might be more efficient than that.

Answer (score 2):

How you plan to use the resulting pixel data is important here.

### Custom Effect

If you only need to offset the alpha for the purpose of rendering (it sounds like you do), you can create a custom shader effect to accomplish this and not have to deal with modifying pixel data. This approach is especially useful if the value is changing over time, and you want to avoid rewriting a bitmap frequently.

If you have never created custom shader effects in WPF, there are some articles on the topic you can read up on. It basically involves writing and compiling a HLSL pixel shader, including the compiled shader as an application resource, creating a C# class that extends `ShaderEffect`, and connecting the effect to the shader.

Here is a quick untested mock up of a shader that theoretically has the effect you are looking for.

**Shader**

```cpp
sampler2D inputSampler : register(S0);
float alpha : register(C0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(inputSampler, uv);
    return float4(color.rgb, clamp(color.a + alpha, 0, 1));
}
```

**Effect**

```cs
class AddAlphaEffect : ShaderEffect
{
    // The Input property is special and will automatically receive the content of the element being rendered
    public Brush Input
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", typeof(AddAlphaEffect), 0);

    public float Alpha
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlphaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Alpha", typeof(float), typeof(AddAlphaEffect),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0f, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));

    public AddAlphaEffect()
    {
        // Reference the compiled shader here, which should be included as a resource in your applciation.
        // ResourceHelper is my own utility that formats URIs for me. The returned URI
        // string will be something like /AssemblyName;component/Effects/AddAlpha.ps
        PixelShader = new PixelShader() { UriSource = ResourceHelper.GetResourceUri("Effects/AddAlpha.ps", relative: true)};

        UpdateShaderValue(AlphaProperty);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Image
    Source="some image">
    <Image.Effect>
        <effects:AddAlphaEffect
            Alpha="0.2" />
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

### Writable Bitmap

If you want to modify the data and hold on to it for a while because it is not changing frequently (or you want to save it out), then you will probably want to use a `WritableBitmap` and update the pixel data directly.

From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Call one of the WritePixels overloads to update and display content in the back buffer automatically.
>
> For greater control over updates, and for multi-threaded access to the back buffer, use the following workflow.
>
> 1. Call the Lock method to reserve the back buffer for updates.
> 2. Obtain a pointer to the back buffer by accessing the BackBuffer property.
> 3. Write changes to the back buffer. Other threads may write changes to
>      the back buffer when the WriteableBitmap is locked.
> 4. Call the AddDirtyRect method to indicate areas that have changed.
> 5. Call the Unlock method to release the back buffer and allow presentation to
>      the screen.

Note that the WritableBitmap method may perform better than a custom shader due to the poor performance of custom shader effects in WPF. It may be worth trying both if you are using this effect enough to raise performance concerns.

Comment: Well explained and thought out answer